# How to check if the player won the game in the first attempt?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing an FPS game in Unity3D. I need to add a check to see whether the player has won the level in the first attempt.

I have the winning condition like this:

```
 if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length)
  {
     Time.timeScale = 0f;
     winUI.SetActive(true);  
     SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
  }
```

I just need to add another check inside the if, to check if it is the first attempt or not. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you could do this. If you need the 'first attempt' to be for the current game session then a simple property on that class would suffice or a static class that holds that data.

If you need the 'first attempt' across game sessions just use playerprefs.

Call this when your level starts

```
var attempt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstAttempt");

// Check that it has not been set before
if (attempt != 1 || attempt != 0) 
{
  // First Attempt
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstAttempt", 1);
} else if (attempt == 0) {
  // Second attempt
}
```

Then in your end game function

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstAttempt") == 1)
{
  //First attempt
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstAttempt", 0)
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try and reply back. But a small question, what you suggested will be applied even when I quit the entire game and open it back? or only during the one whole session until unity is closed? .

Comment: PlayerPrefs get saved to disk so yes it will be persistent across sessions/player launches. Have a look at the docs I referenced. You can also call PlayerPrefs.Save() to ensure that they get saved. Unity doesn't always save by itself.

Comment: So I tried the if else in the Start() and the PlayerPrefs.Save(); in Update(). What I got is the first time I play the level it prints "First attempt" from the if statement and the second time I reload the level it prints "Not First Attempt" from else block. after that, it prints first again and then Not first and so on. why is that happening?

Comment: Ah that is my 2 second dodgy logic when I wrote the answer. Every second time FirstAttempt != 1 so it repeats. I will update that when I get a chance.

Comment: ok. I will be waiting

Comment: Okashi, that should fix your problem now

Comment: currently I don't have end game function. but do you mean OnDestroy()?

Comment: I tried it prints first attempts always. for this line: 
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstAttempt" == 0) you meant 
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstAttempt" , 0) right?

Comment: Ah yes I did...